# React-Redux-Sagas - not returning response -not showing errors

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am working on a Redux application using Sagas, when I call an action creator it returns and action and it does call the API via the Sagas, however, I see that I get no response inside of my Saga function. I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried it all, if anyone has any advice I will appreciate it. Thanks

sagas.js

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { createMatrix } from './utils';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import { CREATE_MATRIX_REQUEST, CREATE_MATRIX_SUCCESS, CREATE_MATRIX_ERROR } from './constants';

export function* createMatrixSaga(action) {
   try {
      //Calls the API and sends payload
      const result = yield call(createMatrix, action.data);
      // We send an action that tells Redux we're sending a payload
      console.log(result)
      yield put({type: CREATE_MATRIX_SUCCESS, success: result});
      //Forward to /reports once actions is sent
      // yield call(forwardTo, '/reports');

   } catch(error) {
     // We send an action that tells Redux we're sending an error
     yield put({type: CREATE_MATRIX_ERROR, error: error });
   }
}


function* watchFetchData() {
  // We send an action that tells Redux we're sending a request
    yield takeEvery(CREATE_MATRIX_REQUEST, createMatrixSaga);
}


export default [
  watchFetchData,
];

// Little helper function to abstract going to different pages
export function* forwardTo(location) {
  yield call(browserHistory.push, location);
}
```

utils.js

```
   import axios from 'axios';
    import cookie from 'react-cookie';


    export function createMatrix({domain, kw}) {

      var url = '';
      var keywords = kw;
      var encoded = encodeURI(keywords);
      var data = {
         key: '',
         keywords: encoded,
         analysisname: domain,
         country:1,
         location:null,
         trafficstats:false,
         use_majestic_api:false
      }
      axios.post(url, data).then((response) => {
          return response.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, 'This a big error')
        throw error
      });
    }


    export default createMatrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer basically I forgot to return my promise in my function

```
import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';


export function createMatrix({domain, kw}) {

  var url = 'https://termexplorer.com/api/keyword-analyzer/new';
  var keywords = kw;
  var encoded = encodeURI(keywords);
  var data = {
     key: 'f3800f11c8266f16a8943981cdd01192',
     keywords: encoded,
     analysisname: domain,
     country:1,
     location:null,
     trafficstats:false,
     use_majestic_api:false
  }
  return axios.post(url, data).then((response) => {
      return response.data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, 'This a big error')
    throw error
  });
}


export default createMatrix;
```